# Fill area between stacked lines with pgfplot

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

[image]

I'd like to recreate the above figure in pgfplots. Unfortunately, if I use the `stacked plots` option

```
%%%%%%%%%%% MISC
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\pagestyle{empty} % Suppresses page number

%%%%%%%%%%% PLOTTING
\usepackage{tikz} % Engine for pgfplots
\usepackage{pgfplots} % For inline plotting
%\pgfplotsset{compat=1.15} % For pgfplot backwards compatibility

\pgfplotsset{compat=newest,
        width=10cm,
        height=7cm,
        xtick pos=left,
        ytick pos=left
        }

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
            stack plots=y,
            area style,
            enlarge x limits=false
            ]
\addplot [name path=A, blue] table [x=Year, y=Coal, col sep=comma] {data.csv};
\addplot [name path=B, red] table [x=Year, y=Oil, col sep=comma] {data.csv};
\addplot [grey] fill between[of=A and B];
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

I only get an error from the `fillbetween` package:

> ! Package pgf Error: fill between: the mandatory argument 'of= and  is missing or has empty arguments. Please
>   ensure that the option has been set and that both path names have been
>   assigned (perhaps you need 'name path global=A' somewhere?)

It works fine for

```
%%%%%%%%%%% MISC
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\pagestyle{empty} % Suppresses page number

%%%%%%%%%%% PLOTTING
\usepackage{tikz} % Engine for pgfplots
\usepackage{pgfplots} % For inline plotting
%\pgfplotsset{compat=1.15} % For pgfplot backwards compatibility

\pgfplotsset{compat=newest,
        width=10cm,
        height=7cm,
        xtick pos=left,
        ytick pos=left
        }

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[]
\addplot [name path=A, blue] table [x=Year, y=Coal, col sep=comma] {data.csv};
\addplot [name path=B, red] table [x=Year, y=Oil, col sep=comma] {data.csv};
\addplot [grey] fill between[of=A and B];
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

but that defeats the purpose of my graph. How can I get to my desired output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You actually don't need the `fillbetween` library to achieve what you want. For details please have a look at the comments in the code.

```
% used PGFPlots v1.16
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
% "simple" version when the fill color equals the draw color
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        stack plots=y,
        no markers,
        % options that are common to all `\addplot` commands
        every axis plot/.append style={
            % add the fill color to each `\addplot`
            % (`.` is an abbreviation for the "current color")
            fill=.,
        },
    ]
        % appended `\closedcycle` to each `\addplot` command
        \addplot coordinates {(0,1) (1,1) (2,2) (3,2)} \closedcycle;
        \addplot coordinates {(0,1) (1,1) (2,2) (3,2)} \closedcycle;
        \addplot coordinates {(0,1) (1,1) (2,2) (3,2)} \closedcycle;
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

% not so simple version when the fill color does not equal the draw color
\begin{tikzpicture}
    % first draw the filled areas in a plot
    \begin{axis}[
        stack plots=y,
        no markers,
        every axis plot post/.append style={
            % here we don't want to draw the lines ...
            draw=none,
            % but only the (filled) areas
            fill=.!25,
        },
        % we don't want to draw the axis lines etc. twice
        axis lines=none,
    ]
        \addplot coordinates {(0,1) (1,1) (2,2) (3,2)} \closedcycle;
        \addplot coordinates {(0,1) (1,1) (2,2) (3,2)} \closedcycle;
        \addplot coordinates {(0,1) (1,1) (2,2) (3,2)} \closedcycle;
    \end{axis}
    % second draw the lines in a plot
    \begin{axis}[
        stack plots=y,
        no markers,
    ]
        \addplot coordinates {(0,1) (1,1) (2,2) (3,2)};
        \addplot coordinates {(0,1) (1,1) (2,2) (3,2)};
        \addplot coordinates {(0,1) (1,1) (2,2) (3,2)};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: image showing the result of above code]